# How to get rev id right after auditing when using Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, audit, hibernate-envers

I'm using Hibernate Envers for auditing. It works fine. However, I'm try to get the rev id right after modifying the data. I have CustomRevisionEntity as below:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity; 
import org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity;
import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionEntity;

@Entity
@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionListener.class)
public class CustomRevisionEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 3775550420286576001L;

  private String username;

  public String getUsername() {
      return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
      this.username = username;
  }
}
```

And CustomRevisionListener:

```
import org.golf.repository.domain.entity.CustomRevisionEntity;
import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionListener;

public class CustomRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {

    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        CustomRevisionEntity revision = (CustomRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;
        revision.setUsername("username"); // For testing
    }  
}
```

So, when for example update address like below, how to get the rev id?

```
public class TestClass {
    updateAddress(address);

    // how to get rev id here?
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem by myself. Just add another attribute e.g. revId in the CustomRevisionEntity class. It will add a new column revid in the customrevisionentity table. And in the CustomRevisionListener class, add something like `revision.setRevId(RevMapper.getRevId());`, the RevMapper is the class that contains the static attribute revId, getter and setter. So in the TestClass, you need to set the revId using `RevMapper.setRevId(id);`

Above is just a simple explanation, and you need to consider how the revId is generated, etc.